# How to setup radio button in jpanel within the jframe?

Tags: java, radio-button, jframe, jpanel

The radio buttons don't seem to be grouped together properly as one of them is slightly slanting towards the left. I am not sure what the error is. Everything in the code seems fine to me...I am not sure what is missing.
I have attached an image below showing the problem. The Ide I am using is NetBeans.

Thank you in advanced! :)

[image: barbeque is slightly slanted to left]

```
 package pizzaorder2;

 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
 import java.awt.FlowLayout;
 import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
 import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class PizzaOrder2 extends JFrame { 


public static void main(String[] args) {

  JFrame frame = new PizzaOrder2();


   JRadioButton tomato = new JRadioButton("Tomato");
   JRadioButton barbeque = new JRadioButton("Barbeque");  
   ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
   group.add(tomato);
   group.add(barbeque);
   JPanel radiopanel = new JPanel();
   radiopanel.add(tomato);
   radiopanel.add(barbeque);
   frame.getContentPane().add(radiopanel);
   radiopanel.setBounds(240,330,110,70);
   radiopanel.setOpaque(false);
   tomato.setForeground(Color.white);
   barbeque.setForeground(Color.white);


    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setSize(600, 700);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(40, 80, 120));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);


    }

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adjusting radiopanel to this:

```
JPanel radiopanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
```

to explain a little better, you're just setting it up so items align on the left, rather than the center (which I believe is default). You will need to import FlowLayout for this.

Comment: glad to help :)